# Moving input radio buttons with CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I wish to move my radiobuttons under each of the selections. Radiobutton "test1" under the first selection and radiobutton "test2" under the second selection. That is, the radiobuttons are below the selection, but next to each other.

How do I do that? I do not wish to use tables or br. I would like to use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets); how should I style my CSS?

```
  <form name="test">
    <label style="float:left;">test</label>
    <input style="display:block" />
    <label style="float:left;">test</label>
    <input style="display:block" />
    <label style="float:left;">test</label>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <select>
       <option>a</option>
       <option>b</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="test1">
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="test2">
</form>
```

[image]

If I add more than one radio box:

I tried using `+` (adjacent sibling selector) in CSS, but I think it is because the position is absolute. So the next "children" won't align horizontally. I think this is the easiest/"neat" way of doing it.

So I tried to position it relatively (the first radio box) and `float:left`. But it positions itself too high.

Comment: Did not understand your question please ellaborate it

Comment: Can you show us the desired output you're trying to achieve in a table or an image?

Comment: @Ultimater of course sorry if my english isnt good.

Comment: @RajeshPatel sorry i will add image to make it easier.

Comment: *i do not wish to use tables or br* did you try blindfold? with one hand tied behind your back?

Comment: @edc65 thanks for replying, but read Moogs and Sage Arslan answers. they have come up with terrific solution(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is each radio button underneath each select element using only CSS without changing your HTML.

```
form {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 30px;
}

input[type="radio"]:last-child {
  left: 70px;
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3w16q179/1/**

More than 2 radio buttons:

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3w16q179/6/**

Comment: This will fail if the select inputs have variable widths. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w16q179/2/)

Comment: @SageArslan you are correct. Dirty fix is to set fixed width on select element https://jsfiddle.net/g83Lty73/1/ .

Comment: @Moogs great suggestion; im still new at this but with your help (last-child) and i've been able to learn new things: [http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048]

Comment: @SageArslan super, thanks for expanding the problem and creating a solution. thanks everyone for your contribution!

Comment: @Moogs just a followup question; in situations where there are more than two radioboxes, how would i do that. because it doesnt automatically extend.

Comment: @Moogs thanks for replying. ive updated the question since ive expanded the problem a little bit. based on your suggestion i looked about and found adjacent sibling selector but im a bit stuck. check my updated post if you can.

Comment: @Moogs thanks; yeah i did that, i think to make it nice and neat is to break my radiobuttons into a separate "box" or whatever you coding experts call it, and then make a single radiobutton-input-css-class (quite a mouthful) to style them uniformly. i hope it makes sense

Answer (score 4):

This will align the radio buttons below the select inputs, regardless of width of their widths.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <label style="float:left;">test</label>
  <input style="display:block" />
  <label style="float:left;">test</label>
  <input style="display:block" />
  <label style="float:left;">test</label>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio">
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <select>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks alot @Sage Arslan, ive added another dimension to the problem. and if you have suggestions check out my updated question.

Answer (score 3):

AHA! I just figured it out what you're looking for... Each radio button is centered under the select. I got it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <style type = "text/css">

        form * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        form {
            background: White;
            width: 420px;
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }

        fieldset {
            text-align: center;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        label {
            width: 33.33%;
            float: right;
            padding: 6px;
        }

        legend {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 33.33%;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <form name="test">
        <fieldset>
            <label>
                <select>
                 <option>a</option>
                 <option>b</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>
                <select>
                 <option>a longer ooption</option>
                 <option>b</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">
            </label>

            <legend>
                Choose One:
            </legend>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</html>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3jbqjj0f/

Comment: thanks, happy with your solution, but ive added a new wrinkle, check the updated post.

Comment: Are the radio buttons to line-up vertically, under each select ?  Or in a row ?  Also, how many

Comment: horizontally, next to each other. the first two radio button line up under a select; exactly like in your jsfiddle. but then a variable number of radiobuttons in a row (horizontally) after the second radio button. its a bit tricky explaining these things in words check the updated image at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I've included about every permutation I could imagine here:  https://jsfiddle.net/questwithrelish/th8mvjp3/  Take a look at the names of form controls, as well as the "for" attribute in the labels.  I'm duplicating names for inputs in each column, assuming the user is supposed to use only one.  If I'm wrong, well, you get the idea.

Comment: Your HTML is not well-formed. For instance, it is missing `<head>` and `<body>` tags. *[Local HTML validation tool for Firefox](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21279)* might help.

Comment: Uh, for those who didn't realize, this is not intended to be a ready-to-use web page.  Just an example of containing form controls inside blocks to display content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: block` or `display: inherit;`.

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/Ltfyaxzq/)**

Comment: He said he din not want to use <br/> tag

Comment: right with you, I didn't see that `br` , answer updated.

Comment: @jiff thanks for reply. how does inherit work? and in this case what is it inheriting? im not an expert.

Comment: your welcome, however it's look like not a useful answer, I saw your updated picture just now. anyway, if you use `display: inherit` it get parent `property` for self.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not that clear, I think you can use `class`. Just add any class to the input you want to move.

For example:

#### HTML

```
<input type="radio" class="myinput" />
```

#### CSS

```
input.myinput {
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px; /* For top spacing */
}
```

I hope that helps!